# MSE (Media Source Extensions) player not playing fragment due to baseMediaDecodeTime

Tags: typescript, video-player, media-source, fmp4

I am trying to get fragmented Mp4 files to play using MSE in a TypeScript player. I have the fragmented mp4 files being split into the video and audio portions. I am able to play the video and audio after setting the baseMediaDecodeTimes in the tfdt boxes to zero. The issue is that in order to sync the audio with the video, I need to change its baseMediaDecodeTime to something other than zero. When I do this, however, the video wont play (likely due to the fact that it doesn't have the audio for the first couple of milliseconds since I shifted it). The amount of time without audio would not be noticeable so I want to start playing the video. What can I do?